# Calculate Time Difference between consecutive rows based on an condition in SQL Server 2019

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2019

I need to find the time duration between two dates on consecutive rows based on a condition. The date difference has to be calculated between each PUMP Stop and Pump Run event for each ID value. Below is the screenshot of the sample data

[image: Sample]

In the above screenshot, I need to find the time duration between each pump stop and pump run events. The Pump Run event would have multiple types like Pump Run, Pump Run - Auto Restart etc.

I tried with `OUTER APPLY` and also with CTE by listing the dates individually however it didn't work well as the duration needs to be partitioned within the ID value. For me it started giving the difference without partition.

Below is the desired output that I need and the schema and data.

[image: Output]

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[device_data](
    [SiteNumber] [int] NOT NULL,
    [SerialNumber] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Time] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [InfusionID] [bigint] NULL,
    [InfusionStatus] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [EventDescription] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    [ElapsedTime] [nvarchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
INSERT [dbo].[device_data] ([SiteNumber], [SerialNumber], [Time], [InfusionID], [InfusionStatus], [EventDescription], [ElapsedTime]) VALUES (4, 3018462, CAST(N'2020-08-04T07:18:55.000' AS DateTime), 965399291, N'STOPPED', N'Standby activated', N'0:0')
INSERT [dbo].[device_data] ([SiteNumber], [SerialNumber], [Time], [InfusionID], [InfusionStatus], [EventDescription], [ElapsedTime]) VALUES (4, 3018462, CAST(N'2020-08-04T08:06:59.000' AS DateTime), 965399291, N'RUNNING', N'Pump rate updated:; - Rate 22.5 mL/hr', N'0:11')
INSERT [dbo].[device_data] ([SiteNumber], [SerialNumber], [Time], [InfusionID], [InfusionStatus], [EventDescription], [ElapsedTime]) VALUES (4, 3018462, CAST(N'2020-08-04T08:10:31.000' AS DateTime), 965399291, N'STOPPED_ALARM', N'Pump STOP', N'0:15')
INSERT [dbo].[device_data] ([SiteNumber], [SerialNumber], [Time], [InfusionID], [InfusionStatus], [EventDescription], [ElapsedTime]) VALUES (4, 3018462, CAST(N'2020-08-04T08:10:31.000' AS DateTime), 965399291, N'STOPPED_ALARM', N'Downstream Occlusion!', N'0:15')
INSERT [dbo].[device_data] ([SiteNumber], [SerialNumber], [Time], [InfusionID], [InfusionStatus], [EventDescription], [ElapsedTime]) VALUES (4, 3018462, CAST(N'2020-08-04T08:10:37.000' AS DateTime), 965399291, N'STOPPED', N'Downstream Occl Clr''d', N'0:15')
INSERT [dbo].[device_data] ([SiteNumber], [SerialNumber], [Time], [InfusionID], [InfusionStatus], [EventDescription], [ElapsedTime]) VALUES (4, 3018462, CAST(N'2020-08-04T08:10:37.000' AS DateTime), 965399291, N'RUNNING', N'Pump RUN - Auto-restart', N'0:15')
INSERT [dbo].[device_data] ([SiteNumber], [SerialNumber], [Time], [InfusionID], [InfusionStatus], [EventDescription], [ElapsedTime]) VALUES (4, 3018462, CAST(N'2020-08-04T08:14:30.000' AS DateTime), 965399291, N'STOPPED_ALARM', N'Pump STOP', N'0:19')
INSERT [dbo].[device_data] ([SiteNumber], [SerialNumber], [Time], [InfusionID], [InfusionStatus], [EventDescription], [ElapsedTime]) VALUES (4, 3018462, CAST(N'2020-08-04T08:14:30.000' AS DateTime), 965399291, N'STOPPED_ALARM', N'Downstream Occlusion!', N'0:19')
INSERT [dbo].[device_data] ([SiteNumber], [SerialNumber], [Time], [InfusionID], [InfusionStatus], [EventDescription], [ElapsedTime]) VALUES (4, 3018462, CAST(N'2020-08-04T08:14:33.000' AS DateTime), 965399291, N'STOPPED', N'Downstream Occl Clr''d', N'0:19')
INSERT [dbo].[device_data] ([SiteNumber], [SerialNumber], [Time], [InfusionID], [InfusionStatus], [EventDescription], [ElapsedTime]) VALUES (4, 3018462, CAST(N'2020-08-04T08:14:33.000' AS DateTime), 965399291, N'RUNNING', N'Pump RUN - KVO', N'0:19')
INSERT [dbo].[device_data] ([SiteNumber], [SerialNumber], [Time], [InfusionID], [InfusionStatus], [EventDescription], [ElapsedTime]) VALUES (4, 3018462, CAST(N'2020-08-04T08:26:45.000' AS DateTime), 965399291, N'RUNNING', N'Pump rate updated:; - Rate 15 mL/hr', N'0:31')
INSERT [dbo].[device_data] ([SiteNumber], [SerialNumber], [Time], [InfusionID], [InfusionStatus], [EventDescription], [ElapsedTime]) VALUES (4, 3018462, CAST(N'2020-08-04T08:35:14.000' AS DateTime), 965399291, N'RUNNING_TITRATE', N'OK not pressed!; - value not accepted', N'0:39')
INSERT [dbo].[device_data] ([SiteNumber], [SerialNumber], [Time], [InfusionID], [InfusionStatus], [EventDescription], [ElapsedTime]) VALUES (4, 3018462, CAST(N'2020-08-04T08:35:14.000' AS DateTime), 965399291, N'RUNNING_TITRATE', N'Value Entry Timeout!', N'0:39')
INSERT [dbo].[device_data] ([SiteNumber], [SerialNumber], [Time], [InfusionID], [InfusionStatus], [EventDescription], [ElapsedTime]) VALUES (4, 3018462, CAST(N'2020-08-04T08:35:21.000' AS DateTime), 965399291, N'RUNNING_TITRATE', N'Value Entry TO Clr''d', N'0:39')
INSERT [dbo].[device_data] ([SiteNumber], [SerialNumber], [Time], [InfusionID], [InfusionStatus], [EventDescription], [ElapsedTime]) VALUES (4, 3018462, CAST(N'2020-08-04T08:35:21.000' AS DateTime), 965399291, N'STOPPED', N'Pump STOP', N'0:39')
INSERT [dbo].[device_data] ([SiteNumber], [SerialNumber], [Time], [InfusionID], [InfusionStatus], [EventDescription], [ElapsedTime]) VALUES (4, 3018462, CAST(N'2020-08-04T08:35:23.000' AS DateTime), 965399291, N'STOPPED', N'REVIEW key pressed', N'0:39')
INSERT [dbo].[device_data] ([SiteNumber], [SerialNumber], [Time], [InfusionID], [InfusionStatus], [EventDescription], [ElapsedTime]) VALUES (4, 3018462, CAST(N'2020-08-04T08:35:28.000' AS DateTime), 965399291, N'RUNNING', N'Pump RUN', N'0:39')
INSERT [dbo].[device_data] ([SiteNumber], [SerialNumber], [Time], [InfusionID], [InfusionStatus], [EventDescription], [ElapsedTime]) VALUES (4, 3018462, CAST(N'2020-08-04T08:36:39.000' AS DateTime), 965399291, N'RUNNING', N'REVIEW key pressed', N'0:41')
INSERT [dbo].[device_data] ([SiteNumber], [SerialNumber], [Time], [InfusionID], [InfusionStatus], [EventDescription], [ElapsedTime]) VALUES (4, 3018462, CAST(N'2020-08-04T08:36:42.000' AS DateTime), 965399291, N'STOPPED', N'User STOP', N'0:41')
INSERT [dbo].[device_data] ([SiteNumber], [SerialNumber], [Time], [InfusionID], [InfusionStatus], [EventDescription], [ElapsedTime]) VALUES (4, 3018462, CAST(N'2020-08-04T08:36:43.000' AS DateTime), 965399291, N'STOPPED', N'REVIEW key pressed', N'0:41')
INSERT [dbo].[device_data] ([SiteNumber], [SerialNumber], [Time], [InfusionID], [InfusionStatus], [EventDescription], [ElapsedTime]) VALUES (4, 3018462, CAST(N'2020-08-04T08:36:44.000' AS DateTime), 965399291, N'STOPPED', N'Standby activated', N'0:41')
INSERT [dbo].[device_data] ([SiteNumber], [SerialNumber], [Time], [InfusionID], [InfusionStatus], [EventDescription], [ElapsedTime]) VALUES (4, 3018462, CAST(N'2020-08-04T08:50:20.000' AS DateTime), 965399291, N'RUNNING', N'Pump RUN', N'0:41')
INSERT [dbo].[device_data] ([SiteNumber], [SerialNumber], [Time], [InfusionID], [InfusionStatus], [EventDescription], [ElapsedTime]) VALUES (4, 3018462, CAST(N'2020-08-04T08:50:37.000' AS DateTime), 965399291, N'RUNNING_TITRATE', N'OK not pressed!; - value not accepted', N'0:41')
INSERT [dbo].[device_data] ([SiteNumber], [SerialNumber], [Time], [InfusionID], [InfusionStatus], [EventDescription], [ElapsedTime]) VALUES (4, 3018462, CAST(N'2020-08-04T08:50:37.000' AS DateTime), 965399291, N'RUNNING_TITRATE', N'Value Entry Timeout!', N'0:41')
INSERT [dbo].[device_data] ([SiteNumber], [SerialNumber], [Time], [InfusionID], [InfusionStatus], [EventDescription], [ElapsedTime]) VALUES (4, 3018462, CAST(N'2020-08-04T08:50:43.000' AS DateTime), 965399291, N'RUNNING_TITRATE', N'Value Entry TO Clr''d', N'0:41')
INSERT [dbo].[device_data] ([SiteNumber], [SerialNumber], [Time], [InfusionID], [InfusionStatus], [EventDescription], [ElapsedTime]) VALUES (4, 3018462, CAST(N'2020-08-04T08:50:47.000' AS DateTime), 965399291, N'RUNNING', N'Pump rate updated:; - Rate 15 mL/hr', N'0:41')
INSERT [dbo].[device_data] ([SiteNumber], [SerialNumber], [Time], [InfusionID], [InfusionStatus], [EventDescription], [ElapsedTime]) VALUES (4, 3018462, CAST(N'2020-08-04T08:53:06.000' AS DateTime), 965399291, N'RUNNING', N'Pump rate updated:; - Rate 7.5 mL/hr', N'0:43')
INSERT [dbo].[device_data] ([SiteNumber], [SerialNumber], [Time], [InfusionID], [InfusionStatus], [EventDescription], [ElapsedTime]) VALUES (4, 3018462, CAST(N'2020-08-04T09:05:06.000' AS DateTime), 965399291, N'RUNNING_TITRATE', N'OK not pressed!; - value not accepted', N'0:55')
INSERT [dbo].[device_data] ([SiteNumber], [SerialNumber], [Time], [InfusionID], [InfusionStatus], [EventDescription], [ElapsedTime]) VALUES (4, 3018462, CAST(N'2020-08-04T09:05:06.000' AS DateTime), 965399291, N'RUNNING_TITRATE', N'Value Entry Timeout!', N'0:55')
INSERT [dbo].[device_data] ([SiteNumber], [SerialNumber], [Time], [InfusionID], [InfusionStatus], [EventDescription], [ElapsedTime]) VALUES (4, 3018462, CAST(N'2020-08-04T09:05:12.000' AS DateTime), 965399291, N'RUNNING_TITRATE', N'Value Entry TO Clr''d', N'0:55')
INSERT [dbo].[device_data] ([SiteNumber], [SerialNumber], [Time], [InfusionID], [InfusionStatus], [EventDescription], [ElapsedTime]) VALUES (4, 3018462, CAST(N'2020-08-04T09:05:12.000' AS DateTime), 965399291, N'STOPPED', N'User STOP', N'0:55')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[device_data] ([SiteNumber], [SerialNumber], [Time], [InfusionID], [InfusionStatus], [EventDescription], [ElapsedTime]) VALUES (4, 3018462, CAST(N'2020-08-05T06:20:37.000' AS DateTime), 965399291, N'STOPPED', N'Infusion Complete', N'4:39')
INSERT [dbo].[device_data] ([SiteNumber], [SerialNumber], [Time], [InfusionID], [InfusionStatus], [EventDescription], [ElapsedTime]) VALUES (4, 3018462, CAST(N'2020-08-05T06:20:56.000' AS DateTime), 5966228461, N'STOPPED', N'Weight  - 62  kg', N'0:0')
INSERT [dbo].[device_data] ([SiteNumber], [SerialNumber], [Time], [InfusionID], [InfusionStatus], [EventDescription], [ElapsedTime]) VALUES (4, 3018462, CAST(N'2020-08-05T06:20:58.000' AS DateTime), 5966228461, N'STOPPED', N'Weight  - 62  kg', N'0:0')
INSERT [dbo].[device_data] ([SiteNumber], [SerialNumber], [Time], [InfusionID], [InfusionStatus], [EventDescription], [ElapsedTime]) VALUES (4, 3018462, CAST(N'2020-08-05T06:20:58.000' AS DateTime), 5966228461, N'STOPPED', N'Weight confirmed', N'0:0')
INSERT [dbo].[device_data] ([SiteNumber], [SerialNumber], [Time], [InfusionID], [InfusionStatus], [EventDescription], [ElapsedTime]) VALUES (4, 3018462, CAST(N'2020-08-05T06:21:15.000' AS DateTime), 5966228461, N'STOPPED', N'Standby activated', N'0:0')
INSERT [dbo].[device_data] ([SiteNumber], [SerialNumber], [Time], [InfusionID], [InfusionStatus], [EventDescription], [ElapsedTime]) VALUES (4, 3018462, CAST(N'2020-08-05T06:21:23.000' AS DateTime), 5966228461, N'STOPPED', N'AC plugged in', N'0:0')
INSERT [dbo].[device_data] ([SiteNumber], [SerialNumber], [Time], [InfusionID], [InfusionStatus], [EventDescription], [ElapsedTime]) VALUES (4, 3018462, CAST(N'2020-08-05T06:21:23.000' AS DateTime), 5966228461, N'STOPPED', N'Battery Low!', N'0:0')
INSERT [dbo].[device_data] ([SiteNumber], [SerialNumber], [Time], [InfusionID], [InfusionStatus], [EventDescription], [ElapsedTime]) VALUES (4, 3018462, CAST(N'2020-08-05T06:21:24.000' AS DateTime), 5966228461, N'STOPPED', N'Batt Low Clr''d', N'0:0')
INSERT [dbo].[device_data] ([SiteNumber], [SerialNumber], [Time], [InfusionID], [InfusionStatus], [EventDescription], [ElapsedTime]) VALUES (4, 3018462, CAST(N'2020-08-05T06:23:31.000' AS DateTime), 5966228461, N'STOPPED', N'Inactivity alarm', N'0:0')
INSERT [dbo].[device_data] ([SiteNumber], [SerialNumber], [Time], [InfusionID], [InfusionStatus], [EventDescription], [ElapsedTime]) VALUES (4, 3018462, CAST(N'2020-08-05T06:23:44.000' AS DateTime), 5966228461, N'STOPPED', N'Inactivity Clr''d', N'0:0')
INSERT [dbo].[device_data] ([SiteNumber], [SerialNumber], [Time], [InfusionID], [InfusionStatus], [EventDescription], [ElapsedTime]) VALUES (4, 3018462, CAST(N'2020-08-05T06:25:44.000' AS DateTime), 5966228461, N'STOPPED', N'Inactivity alarm', N'0:0')
INSERT [dbo].[device_data] ([SiteNumber], [SerialNumber], [Time], [InfusionID], [InfusionStatus], [EventDescription], [ElapsedTime]) VALUES (4, 3018462, CAST(N'2020-08-05T06:25:50.000' AS DateTime), 5966228461, N'STOPPED', N'Inactivity Clr''d', N'0:0')
INSERT [dbo].[device_data] ([SiteNumber], [SerialNumber], [Time], [InfusionID], [InfusionStatus], [EventDescription], [ElapsedTime]) VALUES (4, 3018462, CAST(N'2020-08-05T06:25:53.000' AS DateTime), 5966228461, N'STOPPED', N'Standby activated', N'0:0')
INSERT [dbo].[device_data] ([SiteNumber], [SerialNumber], [Time], [InfusionID], [InfusionStatus], [EventDescription], [ElapsedTime]) VALUES (4, 3018462, CAST(N'2020-08-05T07:58:07.000' AS DateTime), 5966228461, N'RUNNING', N'Pump RUN', N'0:0')
INSERT [dbo].[device_data] ([SiteNumber], [SerialNumber], [Time], [InfusionID], [InfusionStatus], [EventDescription], [ElapsedTime]) VALUES (4, 3018462, CAST(N'2020-08-05T08:06:24.000' AS DateTime), 5966228461, N'RUNNING', N'Pump rate updated:; - Rate 55.8 mL/hr', N'0:8')
INSERT [dbo].[device_data] ([SiteNumber], [SerialNumber], [Time], [InfusionID], [InfusionStatus], [EventDescription], [ElapsedTime]) VALUES (4, 3018462, CAST(N'2020-08-05T08:07:31.000' AS DateTime), 5966228461, N'STOPPED_ALARM', N'Pump STOP', N'0:9')
INSERT [dbo].[device_data] ([SiteNumber], [SerialNumber], [Time], [InfusionID], [InfusionStatus], [EventDescription], [ElapsedTime]) VALUES (4, 3018462, CAST(N'2020-08-05T08:07:31.000' AS DateTime), 5966228461, N'STOPPED_ALARM', N'Downstream Occlusion!', N'0:9')
INSERT [dbo].[device_data] ([SiteNumber], [SerialNumber], [Time], [InfusionID], [InfusionStatus], [EventDescription], [ElapsedTime]) VALUES (4, 3018462, CAST(N'2020-08-05T08:07:36.000' AS DateTime), 5966228461, N'STOPPED', N'Downstream Occl Clr''d', N'0:9')
INSERT [dbo].[device_data] ([SiteNumber], [SerialNumber], [Time], [InfusionID], [InfusionStatus], [EventDescription], [ElapsedTime]) VALUES (4, 3018462, CAST(N'2020-08-05T08:07:36.000' AS DateTime), 5966228461, N'RUNNING', N'Pump RUN - Auto-restart', N'0:9')
INSERT [dbo].[device_data] ([SiteNumber], [SerialNumber], [Time], [InfusionID], [InfusionStatus], [EventDescription], [ElapsedTime]) VALUES (4, 3018462, CAST(N'2020-08-05T09:21:30.000' AS DateTime), 5966228461, N'STOPPED_ALARM', N'Pump STOP', N'1:23')
INSERT [dbo].[device_data] ([SiteNumber], [SerialNumber], [Time], [InfusionID], [InfusionStatus], [EventDescription], [ElapsedTime]) VALUES (4, 3018462, CAST(N'2020-08-05T09:21:30.000' AS DateTime), 5966228461, N'STOPPED_ALARM', N'Downstream Occlusion!', N'1:23')
INSERT [dbo].[device_data] ([SiteNumber], [SerialNumber], [Time], [InfusionID], [InfusionStatus], [EventDescription], [ElapsedTime]) VALUES (4, 3018462, CAST(N'2020-08-05T09:21:34.000' AS DateTime), 5966228461, N'STOPPED', N'Downstream Occl Clr''d', N'1:23')
INSERT [dbo].[device_data] ([SiteNumber], [SerialNumber], [Time], [InfusionID], [InfusionStatus], [EventDescription], [ElapsedTime]) VALUES (4, 3018462, CAST(N'2020-08-05T09:21:34.000' AS DateTime), 5966228461, N'RUNNING', N'Pump RUN - Auto-restart', N'1:23')
INSERT [dbo].[device_data] ([SiteNumber], [SerialNumber], [Time], [InfusionID], [InfusionStatus], [EventDescription], [ElapsedTime]) VALUES (4, 3018462, CAST(N'2020-08-05T09:31:19.000' AS DateTime), 5966228461, N'STOPPED', N'Infusion Complete', N'1:33')
INSERT [dbo].[device_data] ([SiteNumber], [SerialNumber], [Time], [InfusionID], [InfusionStatus], [EventDescription], [ElapsedTime]) VALUES (4, 3018462, CAST(N'2020-08-05T09:31:19.000' AS DateTime), 5966228461, N'RUNNING_KVO', N'Pump RUN - KVO', N'1:33')
INSERT [dbo].[device_data] ([SiteNumber], [SerialNumber], [Time], [InfusionID], [InfusionStatus], [EventDescription], [ElapsedTime]) VALUES (4, 3018462, CAST(N'2020-08-05T09:31:20.000' AS DateTime), 5966228461, N'RUNNING_KVO', N'Pump rate updated:; - Rate 1 mL/hr', N'1:33')
INSERT [dbo].[device_data] ([SiteNumber], [SerialNumber], [Time], [InfusionID], [InfusionStatus], [EventDescription], [ElapsedTime]) VALUES (4, 3018462, CAST(N'2020-08-05T09:31:20.000' AS DateTime), 5966228461, N'RUNNING_KVO', N'Infusion Complete Alarm!', N'1:33')
INSERT [dbo].[device_data] ([SiteNumber], [SerialNumber], [Time], [InfusionID], [InfusionStatus], [EventDescription], [ElapsedTime]) VALUES (4, 3018462, CAST(N'2020-08-05T09:31:33.000' AS DateTime), 5966228461, N'STOPPED', N'User STOP', N'1:33')
INSERT [dbo].[device_data] ([SiteNumber], [SerialNumber], [Time], [InfusionID], [InfusionStatus], [EventDescription], [ElapsedTime]) VALUES (4, 3018462, CAST(N'2020-08-05T09:31:34.000' AS DateTime), 5966228461, N'STOPPED', N'Infusion Cmpl Clr''d', N'1:33')
INSERT [dbo].[device_data] ([SiteNumber], [SerialNumber], [Time], [InfusionID], [InfusionStatus], [EventDescription], [ElapsedTime]) VALUES (4, 3018462, CAST(N'2020-08-05T09:31:54.000' AS DateTime), 5966228461, N'RUNNING', N'Pump RUN', N'1:33')
INSERT [dbo].[device_data] ([SiteNumber], [SerialNumber], [Time], [InfusionID], [InfusionStatus], [EventDescription], [ElapsedTime]) VALUES (4, 3018462, CAST(N'2020-08-05T10:08:02.000' AS DateTime), 5966228461, N'RUNNING', N'Pump rate updated:; - Rate 44.6 mL/hr', N'2:9')
INSERT [dbo].[device_data] ([SiteNumber], [SerialNumber], [Time], [InfusionID], [InfusionStatus], [EventDescription], [ElapsedTime]) VALUES (4, 3018462, CAST(N'2020-08-05T10:11:03.000' AS DateTime), 5966228461, N'RUNNING_TITRATE', N'OK not pressed!; - value not accepted', N'2:12')
INSERT [dbo].[device_data] ([SiteNumber], [SerialNumber], [Time], [InfusionID], [InfusionStatus], [EventDescription], [ElapsedTime]) VALUES (4, 3018462, CAST(N'2020-08-05T10:11:03.000' AS DateTime), 5966228461, N'RUNNING_TITRATE', N'Value Entry Timeout!', N'2:12')
INSERT [dbo].[device_data] ([SiteNumber], [SerialNumber], [Time], [InfusionID], [InfusionStatus], [EventDescription], [ElapsedTime]) VALUES (4, 3018462, CAST(N'2020-08-05T10:11:06.000' AS DateTime), 5966228461, N'RUNNING_TITRATE', N'Value Entry TO Clr''d', N'2:12')
INSERT [dbo].[device_data] ([SiteNumber], [SerialNumber], [Time], [InfusionID], [InfusionStatus], [EventDescription], [ElapsedTime]) VALUES (4, 3018462, CAST(N'2020-08-05T10:11:07.000' AS DateTime), 5966228461, N'STOPPED', N'User STOP', N'2:12')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[device_data] ([SiteNumber], [SerialNumber], [Time], [InfusionID], [InfusionStatus], [EventDescription], [ElapsedTime]) VALUES (4, 3018462, CAST(N'2020-11-13T09:31:02.000' AS DateTime), 6052778471, N'STOPPED', N'Weight  - 64  kg', N'0:0')
INSERT [dbo].[device_data] ([SiteNumber], [SerialNumber], [Time], [InfusionID], [InfusionStatus], [EventDescription], [ElapsedTime]) VALUES (4, 3018462, CAST(N'2020-11-13T09:31:06.000' AS DateTime), 6052778471, N'STOPPED', N'Weight  - 64  kg', N'0:0')
INSERT [dbo].[device_data] ([SiteNumber], [SerialNumber], [Time], [InfusionID], [InfusionStatus], [EventDescription], [ElapsedTime]) VALUES (4, 3018462, CAST(N'2020-11-13T09:31:06.000' AS DateTime), 6052778471, N'STOPPED', N'Weight confirmed', N'0:0')
INSERT [dbo].[device_data] ([SiteNumber], [SerialNumber], [Time], [InfusionID], [InfusionStatus], [EventDescription], [ElapsedTime]) VALUES (4, 3018462, CAST(N'2020-11-13T09:31:19.000' AS DateTime), 6052778471, N'STOPPED', N'User STOP', N'0:0')
INSERT [dbo].[device_data] ([SiteNumber], [SerialNumber], [Time], [InfusionID], [InfusionStatus], [EventDescription], [ElapsedTime]) VALUES (4, 3018462, CAST(N'2020-11-13T09:31:21.000' AS DateTime), 6052778471, N'STOPPED', N'REVIEW key pressed', N'0:0')
INSERT [dbo].[device_data] ([SiteNumber], [SerialNumber], [Time], [InfusionID], [InfusionStatus], [EventDescription], [ElapsedTime]) VALUES (4, 3018462, CAST(N'2020-11-13T09:31:23.000' AS DateTime), 6052778471, N'STOPPED', N'Standby activated', N'0:0')
INSERT [dbo].[device_data] ([SiteNumber], [SerialNumber], [Time], [InfusionID], [InfusionStatus], [EventDescription], [ElapsedTime]) VALUES (4, 3018462, CAST(N'2020-11-13T10:51:45.000' AS DateTime), 6052778471, N'RUNNING', N'Pump RUN', N'0:0')
INSERT [dbo].[device_data] ([SiteNumber], [SerialNumber], [Time], [InfusionID], [InfusionStatus], [EventDescription], [ElapsedTime]) VALUES (4, 3018462, CAST(N'2020-11-13T10:53:37.000' AS DateTime), 6052778471, N'STOPPED_ALARM', N'Pump STOP', N'0:1')
INSERT [dbo].[device_data] ([SiteNumber], [SerialNumber], [Time], [InfusionID], [InfusionStatus], [EventDescription], [ElapsedTime]) VALUES (4, 3018462, CAST(N'2020-11-13T10:53:37.000' AS DateTime), 6052778471, N'STOPPED_ALARM', N'Downstream Occlusion!', N'0:1')
INSERT [dbo].[device_data] ([SiteNumber], [SerialNumber], [Time], [InfusionID], [InfusionStatus], [EventDescription], [ElapsedTime]) VALUES (4, 3018462, CAST(N'2020-11-13T10:53:46.000' AS DateTime), 6052778471, N'STOPPED', N'Downstream Occl Clr''d', N'0:1')
INSERT [dbo].[device_data] ([SiteNumber], [SerialNumber], [Time], [InfusionID], [InfusionStatus], [EventDescription], [ElapsedTime]) VALUES (4, 3018462, CAST(N'2020-11-13T10:53:46.000' AS DateTime), 6052778471, N'RUNNING', N'Pump RUN - Auto-restart', N'0:1')
INSERT [dbo].[device_data] ([SiteNumber], [SerialNumber], [Time], [InfusionID], [InfusionStatus], [EventDescription], [ElapsedTime]) VALUES (4, 3018462, CAST(N'2020-11-13T10:54:33.000' AS DateTime), 6052778471, N'RUNNING', N'Pump rate updated:; - Rate 30.7 mL/hr', N'0:2')
INSERT [dbo].[device_data] ([SiteNumber], [SerialNumber], [Time], [InfusionID], [InfusionStatus], [EventDescription], [ElapsedTime]) VALUES (4, 3018462, CAST(N'2020-11-13T11:00:44.000' AS DateTime), 6052778471, N'STOPPED_ALARM', N'Pump STOP', N'0:8')
INSERT [dbo].[device_data] ([SiteNumber], [SerialNumber], [Time], [InfusionID], [InfusionStatus], [EventDescription], [ElapsedTime]) VALUES (4, 3018462, CAST(N'2020-11-13T11:00:44.000' AS DateTime), 6052778471, N'STOPPED_ALARM', N'Downstream Occlusion!', N'0:8')
INSERT [dbo].[device_data] ([SiteNumber], [SerialNumber], [Time], [InfusionID], [InfusionStatus], [EventDescription], [ElapsedTime]) VALUES (4, 3018462, CAST(N'2020-11-13T11:00:59.000' AS DateTime), 6052778471, N'STOPPED', N'Downstream Occl Clr''d', N'0:8')
INSERT [dbo].[device_data] ([SiteNumber], [SerialNumber], [Time], [InfusionID], [InfusionStatus], [EventDescription], [ElapsedTime]) VALUES (4, 3018462, CAST(N'2020-11-13T11:00:59.000' AS DateTime), 6052778471, N'RUNNING', N'Pump RUN - Auto-restart', N'0:8')
INSERT [dbo].[device_data] ([SiteNumber], [SerialNumber], [Time], [InfusionID], [InfusionStatus], [EventDescription], [ElapsedTime]) VALUES (4, 3018462, CAST(N'2020-11-13T11:11:04.000' AS DateTime), 6052778471, N'STOPPED_ALARM', N'Pump STOP', N'0:18')
INSERT [dbo].[device_data] ([SiteNumber], [SerialNumber], [Time], [InfusionID], [InfusionStatus], [EventDescription], [ElapsedTime]) VALUES (4, 3018462, CAST(N'2020-11-13T11:11:04.000' AS DateTime), 6052778471, N'STOPPED_ALARM', N'Downstream Occlusion!', N'0:18')
INSERT [dbo].[device_data] ([SiteNumber], [SerialNumber], [Time], [InfusionID], [InfusionStatus], [EventDescription], [ElapsedTime]) VALUES (4, 3018462, CAST(N'2020-11-13T11:11:16.000' AS DateTime), 6052778471, N'STOPPED', N'Downstream Occl Clr''d', N'0:18')
INSERT [dbo].[device_data] ([SiteNumber], [SerialNumber], [Time], [InfusionID], [InfusionStatus], [EventDescription], [ElapsedTime]) VALUES (4, 3018462, CAST(N'2020-11-13T11:11:16.000' AS DateTime), 6052778471, N'RUNNING', N'Pump RUN - Auto-restart', N'0:18')
INSERT [dbo].[device_data] ([SiteNumber], [SerialNumber], [Time], [InfusionID], [InfusionStatus], [EventDescription], [ElapsedTime]) VALUES (4, 3018462, CAST(N'2020-11-13T11:20:14.000' AS DateTime), 6052778471, N'STOPPED_ALARM', N'Pump STOP', N'0:27')
INSERT [dbo].[device_data] ([SiteNumber], [SerialNumber], [Time], [InfusionID], [InfusionStatus], [EventDescription], [ElapsedTime]) VALUES (4, 3018462, CAST(N'2020-11-13T11:20:14.000' AS DateTime), 6052778471, N'STOPPED_ALARM', N'Downstream Occlusion!', N'0:27')
INSERT [dbo].[device_data] ([SiteNumber], [SerialNumber], [Time], [InfusionID], [InfusionStatus], [EventDescription], [ElapsedTime]) VALUES (4, 3018462, CAST(N'2020-11-13T11:20:24.000' AS DateTime), 6052778471, N'STOPPED', N'Downstream Occl Clr''d', N'0:27')
INSERT [dbo].[device_data] ([SiteNumber], [SerialNumber], [Time], [InfusionID], [InfusionStatus], [EventDescription], [ElapsedTime]) VALUES (4, 3018462, CAST(N'2020-11-13T11:20:24.000' AS DateTime), 6052778471, N'RUNNING', N'Pump RUN - Auto-restart', N'0:27')
INSERT [dbo].[device_data] ([SiteNumber], [SerialNumber], [Time], [InfusionID], [InfusionStatus], [EventDescription], [ElapsedTime]) VALUES (4, 3018462, CAST(N'2020-11-13T11:35:09.000' AS DateTime), 6052778471, N'RUNNING', N'Pump rate updated:; - Rate 38.4 mL/hr', N'0:42')
INSERT [dbo].[device_data] ([SiteNumber], [SerialNumber], [Time], [InfusionID], [InfusionStatus], [EventDescription], [ElapsedTime]) VALUES (4, 3018462, CAST(N'2020-11-13T11:40:29.000' AS DateTime), 6052778471, N'RUNNING', N'Pump rate updated:; - Rate 46.1 mL/hr', N'0:47')
INSERT [dbo].[device_data] ([SiteNumber], [SerialNumber], [Time], [InfusionID], [InfusionStatus], [EventDescription], [ElapsedTime]) VALUES (4, 3018462, CAST(N'2020-11-13T11:41:44.000' AS DateTime), 6052778471, N'STOPPED_ALARM', N'Pump STOP', N'0:49')
GO
```

Comment: `I am using SQL Server 2019` ... but you posted Excel screen captures, which don't really help to explain your question.  Please post actual text data instead.

Comment: Don't provide a link to a file sharing site for us to download data; many of the users here are IT professionals and we understand the dangers/foolishness of downloading an unknown file from an unknown person; if you need to provide information with the question, then include it *in* the question. Here, your sample data should be provided as DDL and DML statements, and your expected results as a markdown table.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Since to highlight the logic i have shown it in excel. However I have added the schema and the data now

Comment: Please, add the expected results according to sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT e.*, IIF(EventDescription like 'Pump STOP%',
    DATEDIFF(SECOND, Time, ISNULL((SELECT TOP 1 Time
                                    FROM @events 
                                    WHERE InfusionID = e.InfusionID 
                                        AND Time >= e.Time
                                        AND EventDescription like 'Pump Run%'
                                    ORDER BY Time ASC), GETDATE())), 0) as Duration
FROM @events e
```

`@events` is your `[device_data]` table. What the query does is it goes over all events and for each stop, looks for next start of the pump for the same `InfusionID`. If no start of the pump was found then it takes the current time because the pump must be stopped at the moment. Then it subtracts the 2 dates and returns the duration in seconds. I would highly suggest making a table with definitions of all `EventDescriptions` and using the ID of the description instead of the strings, because doing `EventDescription like 'Pump Run%'` instead of `EventDescriptionID in (1,2,3)` is expensive. This is the result:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `LEAD` for this, along with `DATEDIFF` to get the difference

```sql
WITH cte1 AS (
    SELECT * ,
      NextTime = LEAD(Time) OVER (PARTITION BY SiteNumber, SerialNumber, InfusionID ORDER BY Time)
    FROM device_data dd
    WHERE (EventDescription LIKE 'Pump RUN%' OR EventDescription = 'Pump STOP')
)
SELECT *,
  DATEADD(second, DATEDIFF(second, Time, NextTime), CAST('00:00:00' AS time))
FROM cte1
WHERE EventDescription = 'Pump STOP';
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c3b94078631c4bbe40da0a4b294d5366)

Comment: The code is working fine but the problem is, it filters data for Pump Run and Pump Stop. I need the entire events to be listed as I do also have few other calculation to be done based on the other events. Some thing like, I need to find the number of events between Pump Stop and Pump Run.

Answer (score 0):

According to your sample data, the `EventDescription` value for a Pump Stop event is always `'PUMP STOP'`. At the same time, the `'InfusionStatus'` value for the Pump Run event is always `'RUNNING'`. So to get the time duration between each pump stop and pump run events you can just take a difference of the `Time` values for those consequentive events.

The query would be like this

```
SELECT
    *,
     (
        CASE WHEN EventDescription = 'Pump STOP' THEN 
            CAST(DATEADD(s, 0, (SELECT MIN(r.Time) FROM [dbo].[device_data] r 
                                WHERE r.InfusionID = dd.InfusionID 
                                      AND r.InfusionStatus = 'RUNNING'
                                      AND r.Time > dd.Time) - Time
                        ) AS TIME(0)
                )
        END
     ) AS Duration
FROM [dbo].[device_data] dd
```

This query allows you to use the equals operator on VARCHAR values, which is not as expensive as comparing strings using `LIKE`. At the same time, it allows you to create an index on the `InfusionID`, `Time` and `InfusionStatus` columns, which will be used by the engine when executing a query

```
Index Seek(OBJECT:([fiddle_28f92df378bd46849a963c5fa2f229fc].[dbo].[device_data].[device_data_infusion_id_time_status_idx] AS [r]), SEEK:([r].[InfusionID]=[fiddle_28f92df378bd46849a963c5fa2f229fc].[dbo].[device_data].[InfusionID] as [dd].[InfusionID] AND [r].[Time] > [fiddle_28f92df378bd46849a963c5fa2f229fc].[dbo].[device_data].[Time] as [dd].[Time]),  WHERE:([fiddle_28f92df378bd46849a963c5fa2f229fc].[dbo].[device_data].[InfusionStatus] as [r].[InfusionStatus]=N'RUNNING') ORDERED FORWARD)
```

You can check a working demo and the execution plan [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b448326ba1c63d0608dcd16e192ebaf1)

PS: `CAST` and `DATEADD` are used instead of `DATEDIFF` to format the value as  `hh:mm:ss` as you would expect.